# biblatex footcite and footnote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, mla-style

In a document, I am using

```
\usepackage[style=mla,babel=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

together with the `\footcite` command, and everything is perfect. There is a difficulty when I want to include a reference within a longer footnote containing extra text. I tried something like

```
\footnote{extra text extra text \cite{key} extra text}
```

but the output format of the `\cite` command will not be the same as the format of the `\footcite` command. There must be a work around somewhere but I cannot figure out which one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use of the `prenote` and `postnote` fields can be awkward for footnotes with multiple sentences. This approach also can't generate citation lists with delimiters other than the semicolon. You can define a new citation command that behaves like `\cite` in the body text and like `\footcite` in footnotes, barring the citation wrappers (`\mkbibparens` and `\mkbibfootnote`, respectively).

The document below provides an example called `\textcite`, since `biblatex-mla` doesn't define its own `\textcite` command. The code is adapted from `mla.cbx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\iffootnote{\usebibmacro{cite:init}}{}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\global\booltrue{cbx@mlafootnotes}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:mla:foot}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:mla}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{mla:foot:postnote}}

\makeatother

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\cmd{footcites}.\footcites[See][10--15]{bertram}[compare with][9]{worman}
\cmd{textcite} inside \cmd{footnote}.\footnote{See \textcite[10--15]{bertram}. Compare with \textcite[9]{worman}.}

\cmd{textcite} inside \cmd{footnote}.\footnote{See \textcite[10--15]{companion}. Compare with \textcite[9]{knuth:ct}.}
\cmd{footcites}.\footcites[See][10--15]{companion}[compare with][9]{knuth:ct}

\textcite{companion} showed that...
\textcite[10--15]{knuth:ct} showed that...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. I knew that something like that would be possible but it is way beyond my knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @pluton No problem. Your second comment on lockstep's post was what prompted me to answer.

Comment: ok, I just found a limitation of the proposed solution when `\foreignblockcquote` from the `csquotes` package is used. Also, I do not see any mention of the `footcites` command in the help guide while `footcite` is documented through `\SetCiteCommand{\footcite}` [page 25]. A feature request for the `csquotes` package may be necessary when more than one citation is used in `\foreignblockcquote`.

Comment: @pluton I'm not familiar with `\foreignblockquote`. The status of the author of `csquotes` is [unknown ATM](http://www.texdev.net/2012/04/03/biblatex-status/). You could try posting a new question. I'd use a standard style in the MWE as biblatex-mla is outdated (read: prone to break) with any biblatex version after 1.0.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can put the extra text in the `\footcite` command. From the manual

```
\footcite[ prenote ][ postnote ]{ key }
```

So you could use the pre- and postnote for this. Probably

```
\footcites( pre )( post )[ pre ][ post ]{ key }...[ pre ][ post ]{ key }
```

might fit you even better.

Comment: interesting but I have two different citations in the same footnote.

Comment: @pluton then `\footcites` is what you are looking for! You can have pre- and postnotes for each citation, as well as a pre- and postnote for the entire footnote.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

According to p. 3 of the `biblatex-mla` documentation, *"[w]hen using biblatex-mla for footnotes, the style file will provide full bibliographic detail for the first citation of every source"*. Starting with the second citation, the short form will be used, i.e., `\footcite` will produce the same output as `\cite` (apart from typesetting it as a footnote).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=150pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text.\footcite{A01}

Some text.\footcite{A01}

Some text.\footnote{Text inside a footnote, plus a citation \cite{A01}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but what happens when the citation in the footnote is the first citation?

Comment: @pluton Not the thing you'd like to. :-( You could use jmc's answer as a workaround, though the pre- and postnote arguments aren't design for multi-paragraph text.

Comment: lockstep: I have something like `\footnote{\cite{key1}. The reader may also be interested in~\cite{key2}}` whey `key1` and `key2` are called for the first time.

Comment: @pluton You could use `\footcites`. Again, see jmc's answer.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: @lockstep `\cite` is wrapped in `\mkbibparens`, so inside a footnote it actually doesn't give the same output as `\footcite`.