# bigfoot - Dimension too large (I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.)

Tags: errors, footnotes, dimensions, bigfoot

My MWE is below.  I can produce the following output in `nonstopmode`...

[image: mathematical semiotic]

... but I see these errors in the log:

```
! Dimension too large.
\FN@normaloutput ...\tw@ \fi \fi \ifdim \FN@vsize 
                                                  <\glueshrink \FN@vsize \th...
l.163 \end{table}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
\FN@normaloutput ... \@cclv \vbox spread\FN@vsize 
                                                  {\unvbox \@cclv \boxmaxdep...
l.163 \end{table}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

**Note:** I can trace this to the definition of `\FN@normaloutput` in [`bigfoot.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot), but at that point it gets beyond my depth.  I'm not sure how the "19 feet" come into it.  The MWE is only a small portion of a much bigger document that seems to work fine otherwise.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[article,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{hjelmslev1961prolegomena,
  title={Prolegomena to a Theory of Language},
  author={Hjelmslev, L.},
  year={1961},
  publisher={Univ of Wisconsin Pr}
}
@book{thousand-plateaus,
    author = {Deleuze, G. and Guattari, F.},
    year = {1987},
    title = {A Thousand Plateaus},
    publisher = {University of Minnesota Press},
    note = {(Trans. Brian Massumi)},
    keywords = {philosophy},
}
\end{filecontents}


%% For turning off hypenation globally
% \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{metalogo}


\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            style=nature,%home
            articletitle=true,
            sorting=nyt,
            autocite=superscript,
            isbn=false,
            backref=true,
            firstinits=true, % enforce this so I don't have to mangle by .bib file
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

\let\cite\autocite
\let\parencite\autocite

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50219/biblatex-footcite-and-footnote
%% for a way to combine these into one smart command
%% Is there a way to get the parenthetical stuff to show up, like with natbib?

\usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

%% Use ``ex'' to make the spacing depend on current font, cool!
\DefineFNsymbols*{safestar}{{$*$}{\textdagger}{\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection}{\textparagraph}{\textbardbl}{$*$\hspace{-.3ex}$*$}{\textdagger\textdagger}{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection\textsection}{\textparagraph\textparagraph}{\textbardbl\textbardbl}}%
\setfnsymbol{safestar}


%% before-footnote-space applies if there is no following punctuation%home
 \usepackage[after-comma-space=-.05em,after-dot-space=-.05em,before-footnote-space=.02em]{fnpct}

%% This works but creates double spacing

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[fnsymbol]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{R}[roman]
\MakePerPage{footnoteB}
\MakePerPage{footnoteR}
\let\footnote\footnoteB

\usepackage{fnbreak}

\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\autocite{#2}\footnoteR{(#1)}}
%\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\autocite{#2} $\ullcorner$#1$\ulrcorner$}
\newcommand{\mycitespecial}[2][]{\autocite{#2}(#1)}
%home
 \AdaptNoteOpt\cite\multautocite%home
 \AdaptNoteOpt\mycite\myautocite


\usepackage{rotating}

\setlrmarginsandblock{40mm}{20mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{60mm}{60mm}{*}

\setmarginnotes{14pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\sideparmargin{outer}
\marginparmargin{inner}

\setheadfoot{2\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{5mm}{*}

\chapterstyle{plain}

%%%
\checkandfixthelayout

\setsecindent{1cm}
%\let\footruleskip\relax % for compatibility of memoir and fancyhdr
\let\proportional\ttfamily % for compatibility of memoir and blindtext
\let\sc\scshape
\let\bf\bfseries
\let\it\itfamily
\let\tt\ttfamily
\let\sl\slshape
\let\sf\sffamily


\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%% frenchlinks here will make all the links show up in small caps font
\usepackage[frenchlinks, pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .5},citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1},urlbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}

The basic division into \emph{process} and \emph{system} described in
Chapter
\ref{literature-review}\mycite[pp. 29--30]{hjelmslev1961prolegomena}.
This division was later adapted and popularized by Gilles Deleuze and
F\'elix Guattari\mycite[Chapter 3]{thousand-plateaus}.

\subsection{The mathematical semiotic}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rp{.4\textwidth}p{.4\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf form}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{\bf substance}} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}
\begin{rotate}{90}
{\bf \hspace{-25mm} content}
\end{rotate}
& {\small \textbf{I.} 
Vocabulary use, relative to a static word list (\emph{``defined
  terms''}) or graph (\emph{``the encyclopedia''}); relative to time (\emph{which
  words follow one another in sequence}); and indeed even language
  creation over time, relative to a given community}
& {\small \textbf{III.}  Mathematical discourse, proof, and exposition (\emph{mathematical semantics}) }  \\
\quad & \quad   \\
\noalign{\smallskip}  \noalign{\smallskip}
\begin{rotate}{90}
{\bf \hspace{-20mm} expression}
\end{rotate} & \small \textbf{II.}  Behavior (\emph{such as it is modeled and incentivized within our system's architecture}), including relational behavior, as well as periods of non-observed behavior &
{\small \textbf{IV.} Growth and change of the system itself
  (\emph{considered as a ``grammar of behavior''})}
\\ \noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{An Hjemslevian division of observables \label{hjemslevian}}
\end{table}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: *lol* :-)  that's the point.  Run: `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode example.tex`

Comment: I suggest you clean up the code. The loaded packages, `\noalign`, etc. Further, go commenting structures and packages, to see if you detect where are you getting the error.

Comment: I wonder if the following thread on `comp.text.tex` helps: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/comp.text.tex/bigfoot/comp.text.tex/O1wKdgxofVs/YYGw6m82KCIJ There David Kastrup mentions a development version of `bigfoot` but the current TeXLive version is the same as the one in TL 2010 (the version mentioned in the thread.)

Comment: It seems that `bigfoot` gets confused by the pending float, just as the poster of the question in `comp.text.tex` mentions.

Comment: Did you get any feedback?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - not yet perhaps I should ping him again.

Comment: @JoeCorneli No news?

Comment: nope... I wonder if @dak has an account here?

Comment: @JoeCorneli The `bigfoot` package has been updated (version 2.0 of 2014/10/23); a test on your MWE seems to show that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a package that has been already fixed.

Comment: It clearly wasn't off topic when it was asked!  It could still be relevant to people who are using older versions of the software (i.e. older than 1 month, as of this comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that as of the recent updates to `bigfoot` the above MWE is now working (xref: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)).